# MySQL - Dumping 1TB database with SED to replace definer

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

Im going to dump a large database more than 1TB using MySQLDUMP (unfortunately I have to stick with mysqldump, I can't use mydumper or any other backup tools)

And I want to replace the definer on the fly during the backup.

So if I use sed with dump command, will it take more time than the normal mysqldump?

```
mysqldump db name | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/' > dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

First, dump only the routines, not any of the data.  That way it should be quite fast -- drop a routine, rebuild it.  Rinse, repeat.

As for the regexp, the format should be very regular, so `[ ]*` (or `\s*` can probably be simplified to  .

```
[^*]* -->  .*\*
```

With some guts, simply

```
mysqldump ... | set -e '...' | mysql ...
```

I'm not clear that the regexp does the right thing; please provide a sample.

Comment: Hey Rick, thanks for your response. Regarding the regex, I can use any one of the regexes from here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691087/sed-remove-definer-from-sql-dump)